# Finding each array value in a mysql table imploded column

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

Let's assume I have this array

```
$arr = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9);
```

Then I also have a database table column which the value is imploded

```
column = '3,5,8,2,4';
```

Now I want to run a mysql query on each of the `$arr` value to see if it is in the `column`

I know `FIND_IN_SET` can go just for a string but I don't know if it's possible to do the `FIND_IN_SET` for an array.

Comment: The best solution isn't to use comma-separated data in a database column anyway, but to properly normalize your data

Comment: You could use a query to select possible matches, and then before displaying that data as a match use php's `explode` on the column to make it into an array, and then use php's `in_array` to determine if its an actual match.

Comment: Are you retrieving column based on some other param? Ie you have the column extracted from sql and in a php variable?

Comment: [1, 2, 3, banana, 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad)